# How to programmatically click on single date? 1.6.4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

How to programmatically click on a single date in FullCalendar 1.6.4? Nothing is working.

```
var initialDate = "2023-02-21"
alert(initialDate)
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'select', initialDate, initialDate, true )
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectable read this

Comment: @AwaisRehman please, if you are giving links, provide a link to the relevant version of the documentation. This clearly asks about version 1, so the latest (currently version 6) documentation is very likely to be different in some way.

Comment: @MrSujon `Nothing is working` isn't an error message or a clear problem statement. Is there any console error when you run this code? In what context are you running it? Have you enabled the calendar to be `selectable`? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/selectable . You can't select anything if the feature is not enabled.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/select-method    I want to programmatically selecting a date after Calendar is loaded.

Comment: Yes we know, you already said that. Please reply directly to what I wrote in my comment, otherwise it is difficult to help you any more.

Comment: No error shows like this below  {
    "0": {
        "jQuery360057652467656150062": {
            "fullCalendar": {
                "options": {
 .....

Comment: `shows like this below`...what does? And that's incomplete anyway, and does not tell me anything useful like what I asked for. Please [edit] your question when you have clarifications, and include all relevant information, not a shortened version of it.